# Обращение к данным TypeScript, Angular

Tags: typescript, angular5

Здравствуйте. Есть запрос в Angular 5:

```
http.get(baseUrl + 'api/Student/Students1')                           
.subscribe(result => {
this.std = (result as Students[]);
}, error => console.error(error));
```

Интерфейс:

```
interface Students {
    Address: string;
    Email: string;
    Phone: string;
    StdName: string;
}
```

Записываю данные в std , `public std : Students[]`. У меня там несколько экземпляров. Как обратиться к определенному? (что - то типа  std[1].Email)

Comment: Есть у кого мысли?

Comment: Так в чем проблема обращаться по индексу к элементу массива ?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать `*ngFor="let data of std;"`
и далее уже `<li>{{data.Email}}</li>`

Answer (score -1):

```
std : Students[] = []

http.get(baseUrl + 'api/Student/Students1')                           
    .subscribe((result: Students[]) => {
this.std = result['%Имя возвращаемого массива%'];
console.log(this.std[0].Email);
}, 
error => console.error(error));
```